# C Program that takes file names as command line arguments and keeps count of each character?

Tags: c, input, output, command-line-arguments

I am creating a program that takes filenames (input or output) as command line arguments, reads from the input files, counts each character and prints a list of each count to an output file. If no input file is given, the program should take standard input, and if no output if given, the program should print to standard output.

Two of the main problems I'm having are:

1.If I list multiple input files as command line arguments, only the last file will be read as the input.

2.
 If I give an output file as `"-oresults.txt"` `(argv[j]+2)`, the correct output will be printed to the file, but not if it is given as `"-o results.txt" (argv[j+1])`.

Here is a segment of the code:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
  FILE *in=stdin; FILE *out=stdout; FILE *hold;
  int i, j, c, counts[NUM]={0}, total=0;


  for (j=1;j<argc;j++) {
    if (argv[j][0]=='-') {
      if (argv[j][1]=='o') {
        if (argv[j][2]=='\0')
          out=fopen(argv[j+1],"w");
        if (argv[j][2]!='\0')
          out=fopen((argv[j]+2),"w"); }
 }
    else {
      in=fopen(argv[j],"r");
  }


  while ((c = fgetc(in)) != EOF) {
      counts[c]++;
      total++;
    }
```

Comment: ummm, nice.... so whats the question?

Comment: You should increment the `argv` pointer as you scan through the arguments. Do not try to support both conventions `-ofile` and `-o file`. Specify one or the other; preferrably the latter one. When you see a `-o` argument, which you can recognize as a full string with `strcmp`, you can increment past it using `argv++`, and then take the next argument as the output file name.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of parsing the command line yourself, the typical way is to use `getopt()`.  Check out [the optarg man page](http://linux.die.net/man/3/optarg).   It provides a worked example.

To be more explicit, you would first use `getopt()` to loop through and completely parse your command line first, then perform your counting loops.

Answer (score 0):

```
 -o results.txt
```

Seperated by space makes them 2 different arguments. You need to change the logic and open the file if the second argument is `-o`. Currently you are comparing characters in a single argument. Do something like -

```
if (0 == strcmp(argv[1], "-o"))
{
    // Open the file
```

Answer (score 0):

There are a number of problems in your way of parsing the command-line arguments:

- The `while` loop (that reads input) is run for every argument, even if it only specifies an output file. This causes `stdin` to be read as input if the first argument was an output file.
- When the output file is specified as two arguments, i.e., `-o filename`, you need to skip the filename on the next iteration after reading the `-o` argument, e.g., replace `argv[j + 1]` with `argv[++j]` in the first `fopen`.
- The checks for `argv[j][2] != '\0'` is redundant (though harmless), replace it with `else`.
- `-o` as the last argument causes you to index past the end of `argv`, which will probably just cause `fopen` to fail, but:
- you are not checking for errors with any of the `fopen`s

Other than that, you could have included the complete code, now it is unclear if there are errors left unseen.